# OData Service Versioning

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api

I've written an OData service and have a requirement for versioning using controller directories, for example:

Controllers
 - v1
   - StaffController
 - v2
   - StaffController

I want to type in the uri odata/v1/Staff for version 1 users or odata/v2/Staff for version 2 users.

I've tried implementing my own IHttpControllerSelector and modifying the MapHttpRoute in WebApiConfig but that didn't work out so well.

Would you be able to tell me if I'm going in the right direction and point me to a code sample? Or maybe there's a better way to create versions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this sample helps you, please have a try: https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v3/ODataVersioningSample/

Comment: Just what I was looking for and lots of other excellent OData samples I can use. Thanks!!

Comment: Took me 30 minutes to apply this in my project and it worked out perfect. Thanks again!